# Show that the existence of the Limit of a function as x goes to infinity.

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f:[0,+\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f$ is differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=5$. Show that

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of $$f(x)=5+\frac{\sin x^2}{x+1} ?$$

**Proving that the requested result is wrong.**

For more details have a look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiable-functions-converging-to-zero-whose-derivatives-diverge-part1/).

Comment: Living up to your name, I see

Comment: A $+1$ will ease continuity and differentiability ;-)

Comment: It is possible that using mean value or limit of definition about my question

Answer (score 0):

If you assume *in addition* that the derivative is **uniformly continuous** then the conclusion is true. See [Barbalat's lemma](https://mathpost.asu.edu/~hliu/Things2Explain/Barbalat's%20lemma.pdf).

Comment: In the link you provided, the hypothesis is uniform continuity of $f^\prime$ not of $f$. However the conclusion also holds assuming uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Wouldn't $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$ be a counterexample? $f\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, and the derivative $f'(x)=2\cos(x^2)-\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ is bounded, so the function is Lipschiz continuous and, hence, uniformly continuous. However, the limit of $f'$ does not exist.